# Implementing WaitForSingleObject(GetCurrentThread(),INFINITE) in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, winapi, pthreads, posix

I want to know why `pthread_join(pthread_self(),NULL)` leads to undefined behaviour, but `WaitForSingleObject(GetCurrentThread(),INFINITE)` is fine?

Also, if I want to replace `WaitForSingleObject(GetCurrentThread(),INFINITE)` to work fine in Linux, what equivalent is present?

I am trying to implement a code written with Windows calls to Linux. I am stuck at this line and couldn't find an answer for the question.

Comment: `pthread_join(pthread_self(),NULL)` doesn't lead to undefined behavior, it fails with `EDEADLK`.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour of that call? If you search for that online, what do you find?

Comment: @dimich yes, but if I want to implement WaitForSingleObject on the same thread, what should I do?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I want main thread to wait for spawned or child threads to complete their task. If I write pthread_join for every thread, concept of multithreading doesn't remain , right? I want main thread to wait for all child threads before terminating itself but don't do this wait one by one

Comment: Usually you'd have an array of `pthread_t`'s and a loop that iterates through it joining each one.

Comment: Why does waiting for started threads contradict multithreading?

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject(GetCurrentThread(), INFINITE)` doesn't seem to make much sense. A thread enters the signaled state when it terminates. But that will never happen since the thread is eternally waiting for itself to terminate. What specific problem is this trying to solve?

Comment: @PiyushKumarGupta A thread cannot wait on itself, on any platform. That is a guaranteed deadlock. Your goal contradicts your question. You have to wait on each task individually, not on the thread that creates the tasks. There's no getting around that. At least on Windows, there are APIs to wait on multiple objects at one time, like `WaitForMultipleObjects()`. There is no equivalent of that in pthreads.

Comment: Re "*what equivalent is present?*", `while (1) sleep(10000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_join()` waits for specified thread to terminate. `pthread_join(pthread_self(), NULL)` would attempt to wait for caller thread to terminate, which will never happen. This is obvious deadlock and it has defined behavior: `EDEADLK` error is returned. From [man pthread_join](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html#ERRORS):

> EDEADLK A deadlock was detected (e.g., two threads tried to join with each other); or thread specifies the calling thread.

If you need to wait for multiple threads to terminate, you can join all threads sequentially. Order of joining doesn't matter. Code example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

static void *worker(void *arg)
{
    int idx = (intptr_t)arg;
    printf("thread %i: started\n", idx);

    /* Some pseudo-random delay 1..999 ms */
    struct timespec ts;
    ts.tv_sec = 0;
    ts.tv_nsec = 1000000l * (1 + rand() % 999);
    nanosleep(&ts, NULL);

    printf("thread %i: exiting\n", idx);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    pthread_t threads[5];
    const int num_threads = sizeof(threads)/sizeof(*threads);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
    {
        void *arg = (void *)(intptr_t)i;
        int err = pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, worker, arg);
        if (err != 0)
            abort();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
    {
        printf("main: waiting for thread %i\n", i);

        int err = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            abort();

        printf("main: thread %i terminated\n", i);
    }

    printf("main: all threads exited\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
thread 0: started
thread 1: started
thread 2: started
main: waiting for thread 0
thread 3: started
thread 4: started
thread 0: exiting
main: thread 0 terminated
main: waiting for thread 1
thread 4: exiting
thread 1: exiting
main: thread 1 terminated
main: waiting for thread 2
thread 3: exiting
thread 2: exiting
main: thread 2 terminated
main: waiting for thread 3
main: thread 3 terminated
main: waiting for thread 4
main: thread 4 terminated
main: all threads exited
```